# C++: Какие есть предопределенные макросы (OS и библиотеки)?

Tags: c++, define

Возникла проблема:

Я знаю, что если используется какая-либо операционная система или библиотека (прим.  Например Windows; OpenGL; SFML и др.) используется во время компиляции, то в C++ определяются соответствующие #define.

Можете ли вы написать какие макросы определяются, если программа исполняется в разных операционных системах (По возможности напишите какие определяются #define, если в программе используются самые распространённые библиотеки)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249232/637669

Comment: `g++ -dM -E - </dev/null` покажет все предопределенные макросы. Если вместо /dev/null направить список из `#include <any-file.h>`, то выведет еще и определенные в них макросы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно быстро смогли найти решение вопроса.

`_WIN32`: Windows (Все версии)

`_WIN64`: Windows (64-разрядная версия)

`__unix__`: UNIX

`__APPLE__`: Apple (MacOS и IOS)

`__linux__`: Linux

`__ANDROID__`: Android

`__hpux`: HP-UX

`_AIX`: AIX

`__sun`: Solaris

Если ничего не подходит, значит OC, на которой компилируется программа не является ни одной из вышеперечисленных.

Если вы хотите, вы можете дополнить этот вопрос макросами, которые определяются, когда используются разные библиотеки.

Comment: Довольно быстро смогли найти открыв ссылку из первого комментария к вопросу?) Да вы прям молодец

Comment: MSVC не определяет `__WIN32__`, это делает только MinGW. Правильный макрос - `_WIN32`.

Comment: Нет, комментарии я не читал

Comment: Зря не читали...

Comment: Добавил правки.